# Where is _start symbol likely to be defined

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, riscv

I have some startup assembly for RISCV which defines the `.text` section as beginning at `.globl _start`.

I know what this is - as a disassembly shows me the address, but I cannot see where it is defined. It's not in the linker script and a grep in the build directories shows it is in various binary files, but I cannot find a definition.

I am guessing this appears in a file somewhere as a function of the architecture, but can anyone tell me where? (This is all being built using RISCV GNU cross compilers on Linux)

Comment: The answer to this question involves the internal details of the linker, loader, and startup code. Or to put it another way, the address of `_start` will be assigned at run time, so there is no definition for `grep` to find.

Comment: For my baremetal projects I map `_start` to a fixed address in the linker script. Otherwise I can't guarantee that `_start` is at the right place.

Comment: There should be a `_start:` line that defines the label `_start` in the same source code file as the `.globl _start` directive, otherwise the `.globl _start` directive doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: There is such a line, but it just falls at the start of the .text section, but maybe that's the point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you control it yourself there is usually at least in the gnu tools world a file called crt0.s.  Or perhaps some other name.  Should be one per architecture since it is in assembly language.  It is the default bootstrap, zeros .bss copies .data as needed, etc.

I dont remember if it is part of the C library (glibc, newlib, etc), or if it is added on later by folks that build a toolchain targeting some specific platform.

Not required certainly but it is not uncommon to see _start be the label of the beginning of the binary, it is supposed to be the entry point certainly.  So if you have an operating system/loader that uses a binary with labels present (elf, etc), then it can load the binary and instead of branching to the first address it branches to the entry point.

Comment: indeed. Infact I wrote my own crt.S for this (by hacking together bits of other people's). I now realise that _start is just defined as where that entry code is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

So the `_start` is merely defined as being at the start of the `.text` section, and the address of the `.text` section is defined in the linker script.